# Openshift Login Plugin Jenkins - Invalid Request

Tags: openshift

I tried to setup-up a custom jenkins image, based on the redhat jenkins image. The redhat jenkins image, has the Openshift Login Plugin, installed already.
After, the image started up properly, I tried to login, with my Openshift credentials, but it didn't work.

I just saw the the following error message:

```
"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.","state":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

and there was another message in the OS terminal of the running pod.

I read about several other issues from the Openshift Login Plugin, but also an update to Version 1.0.12 didn't fix my problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Problem was, that I didn't knew, that each Openshift Service Account has a redirect reference - specially configured for one deployment.

I already used the Service Account, I used for the above mentioned Jenkins, for another Jenkins Deployment, because of this Openshift added the redirect reference, configured for this "older" deployment.

In our Openshift Setup (3.11), you aren't able to find the redirection configuration within the Service Account settings that you can find under Resources --> Membership --> Service Accounts. Instead you have to look and edit the YAML File of the Service Account, that you can find under Resources --> Other Resources --> Service Account.

```
serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference.jenkins
```

Since this is quite tricky to find out, I hope that I could possibly save somebody a few hours of searching.